# Calculate average gap size in time series by extracting data from imputeTS functions

Tags: time-series, imputets

I need to calculate the average gap size of a univariate time-series data set. **imputeTS** package generates plots using this data. Is it possible to extract the 'gap size' and the 'number of occurrence' from either `statsNA` or `ggplot_na_gapsize`?
Or is there any other way to find the average size of gaps in a time-series data set?
(You could use `tsNH4` data set from the **imputeTS** package)

(This is my first time asking questions here and I'm fairly new to 'r')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can get the average gap size only indirectly with some extra work with the CRAN version of **imputeTS**.

But I made a quick update to the development version on GitHub.
Now you can also get the average gap size with the `statsNA` function.

Therefore you have to install the new version from GitHub first (since it is not on CRAN yet):

```
library("devtools")
install_github("SteffenMoritz/imputeTS")
```

If you do not have "devtools" installed, then also install this library at the very beginning

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

Afterwards just use the **imputeTS** package as usual.

```
library("imputeTS")

#Example with the tsNH4 dataset
statsNA(tsNH4)
```

This will now print you the following:

> ```
> > statsNA(tsNH4)
>
> [1] "Length of time series:"
> [1] 4552
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Number of Missing Values:"
> [1] 883
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Percentage of Missing Values:"
> [1] "19.4%"
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Number of Gaps:"
> [1] 155
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Average Gap Size:"
> [1] 5.696774
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Stats for Bins"
> [1] "  Bin 1 (1138 values from 1 to 1138) :      233 NAs (20.5%)"
> [1] "  Bin 2 (1138 values from 1139 to 2276) :      433 NAs (38%)"
> [1] "  Bin 3 (1138 values from 2277 to 3414) :      135 NAs (11.9%)"
> [1] "  Bin 4 (1138 values from 3415 to 4552) :      82 NAs (7.21%)"
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Longest NA gap (series of consecutive NAs)"
> [1] "157 in a row"
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Most frequent gap size (series of consecutive NA series)"
> [1] "1 NA in a row (occuring 68 times)"
> [1] "-------------------------"
> [1] "Gap size accounting for most NAs"
> [1] "157 NA in a row (occuring 1 times, making up for overall 157 NAs)"
> ```

As you can see, 'Number of gaps' and 'Average gap size' is now newly added to the output.

You can also access the output as a variable:

```
library("imputeTS")

#To actually get a output object, set print_only to false

out <- statsNA(tsNH4, print_only = F)

# Average gap size
out$average_size_na_gaps

# Number of Gaps
out$number_na_gaps

#Number of NAs
out$number_NAs
```

The updates will also be in the next CRAN update. (thanks for the suggestion)
Just be a little bit careful, since it is a development version - thus not so thoroughly tested as the CRAN version.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks a lot.